# What are useful and proven ways to get good customers?

Tags: customer-service

Some of the visitors on this website are consultants of various kinds, webmasters, SEO experts, web developers, web designers, content writers, you all rock!

**Can you share some unique ways of finding good customers for your web-related business?**

Even if you don't have any website, just services and your skills.

And if you can throw in some ways to keep the good customers, and lose the bad ones (without leaving hard feelings), all the better.

Comment: It is now community wiki

Answer (score 2):

The key to getting good customers in my experience is to first define what a good customer is for your business. Then look at your customers and see what is important to the ones that fit your concept of good customer (it doesn't hurt to ask them for suggestions either). Once you have clearly defined what characteristics make a good customer and what your good customers want/need focus on meeting those needs and be willing to say no to potential customers that don't fit into the good customer category.

Answer (score 1):

This is very relative to the type of site you are running. If you are running a blog and not actually selling much other than advertising you would just want raw vistors, and encourge them to interact.

If you are running an ecommerce site then you want buyers or to strengthen your brand.  In those cases you would sell service, quality, customer satisfaction and what makes you different.  Customer service goes a long ways.  Keeping your users informed or deals, discounts and promotions also helps.  My trick is to ask for registration when someone ads a product to their cart.  Registered cart users can access their cart on other computers.
This is a great way to manage abandoned carts, or to offer your customers promos based on their shopping or browsing habits.

If you are running a SAS (or cloud applicaiton) it is all about reviews. Negative feedback can kill a SAS very quickly.

Last, Nothing is more important to me than the User's Experience.
UI, customer service, and WOW factor.

Comment: Asking users to register when adding a product to basket seems contradictory to providing a good user experience. When I add a product to my cart I either want to carry on shopping or checkout, asking me to register at this point is almost certainly an unwelcome distraction from my purchase.

Comment: I agree, so i dont make it a hard option.  Simply the first time an item is added i say,,, "Product x added to your cart".  With a link to register so that you can access and save your cart from any computer.  or  (in smaller text) continue shopping and dont show this message agian.  Most register. registration at that point is Name, Email, and Phone (optional).  This lets us later reach back the customer and say... What can i do to convince you to buy the products in your cart.  Or i can give you x off if you purchase this week.  Traditional telesales.

Answer (score 0):

I agree at somepoints to Joshak: you need first define good customers according to your business.

A good customer for one business may be a lousy customer to another and vice-versa.

After definition is ready, work on customization for those. Improve content, design and usability to them.

Defining your good customers will help knowing them, and after knowing them you will be able to improve your site efficiently to them.

It is a circle, it requires time and work, but worth the effort, as you can keep and expand to the target public.

Avoiding undesirable customers is tricky. They exists all the time, everywhere. You can just minimize them though customizing to your good customers, reducing their interest in your services or products.

Further, you can define rules for privacy and legal terms that allows you to bam undesired customers, but make this is a way that let you be ethical on bam out those customers, otherwise, this will be as the same as censorship, and no one agree with a dictatorial fashion. Guide yourself through ethics.